# Forgetting to sell some of your Chumatz before Pesach

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, halacha

If someone sold all the chumatz in their home before pesach, but forgot to sell any chumatz left at their place of work, are they allowed to eat the food left in their office after the holiday?

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask one's Rabbi if it happens.

Comment: As I haven't as yet sold my chamutz with my Rabbi this isn't a real concern and didn't want to waste his time now with a hypothetical question. Hoping someone here had some insite or direction.

Comment: Yeah, I have no problem with people analyzing the hypothetical, and clearly, it's too early for this to be a practical problem for you or anyone else this year. I'm just pointing out that regardless of the answers you get below, anyone this actually happens to should talk to their own Rabbi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, your rabbi will ask you and remind you to sell Chametz at your workplace.

If, however, this slipped past you and you remembered (before noon on) Erev Pesach but it was too late to find your rabbi to sign a contract, you could gather two male Jewish witnesses and tell them that all of your chametz belongs to John Doe (pick a non-Jew who you know), and that would be effective as a sale -- even if you never contacted John Doe about the sale.

If you forget to do this before pesach, it would be assur to eat that chametz -- it would be chametz she'avar alav ha pesach.

Comment: Does he need two witnesses or a Beth Din?

Comment: Two kosher witnesses.

Comment: You'd still have to go ask John Doe for permission before eating it after Pesach.